# Raise custom events in C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

I have some Events I created on my own and was wondering on how to raise them when I want.

Probably my application design is also messed up, might take a look at that if you like.

This is the Structure

```
ProgramContext
 - Form MainWindow
  + Control TextBox
  + Control Button
  + ...
```

In this case, the `MainWindow.TextBox` holds some information that is updated quite often at runtime. So, I somehow need it to refresh itself when I want to (so it can reload its data from the database, where the it's stored)

I tried hooking an `EventHandler` to its `Validating`-Event, but that didn't seem to do the trick.

So, basically I have a method that reloads the data in `ProgramContext`

```
DataTable table = _adapter.GetData();
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
  MainWindow.TextBox.Text += table.Text.ToString();
}
```

That needs to be done whenever another method (that writes new data into `table`) is executed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Edit : It seems your question is more about hooking into a specific event, but FWIW below is how to fire custom events in general.

**Handling the TextBox Changed Event**

From what I understand, you want an external party to monitor events raised from a textbox on a Form and then to reload data on another form?

A quick and dirty would be to make the Form TextBox public and then others could subscribe to this event

```
MainForm.textBox1.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox1_TextChanged);
```

OR, in more recent versions of C#:

```
MainForm.textBox1.TextChanged += this.textBox1_TextChanged;
```

**Adding Your own Custom Event**

Another, cleaner way would be to [raise a custom event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9aackb16(v=vs.110).aspx), - e.g. `MyDataChangedEvent` below. This will allow you to abstract away the fact that the changes are coming from a textbox at all.

```
// Assuming you need a custom signature for your event. If not, use an existing standard event delegate
public delegate void myDataChangedDelegate(object sender, YourCustomArgsHere args);

// Expose the event off your component
public event myDataChangedDelegate MyDataChangedEvent;

// And to raise it
var eventSubscribers = MyDataChangedEvent;
if (eventSubscribers != null)
{
   eventSubscribers(this, myCustomArgsHere);
}
```

<del>You might also look at the Ent Lib Composite Application Block and Smart Client Software Factory - this has a very flexible event broking / pub sub mechanism for synchronising across UI "SmartParts" (controls, forms dialogs etc) in a loose-coupled fashion.</del> *(CAB is now very dated).*

Comment: In your example, instead of declaring a new delegate, it'd be clearer to just use the generic `EventHandler` as in `public event EventHandler<YourCustomArgsHere> MyEvent`

Comment: I also tried hooking to `TextChanged`, but that will end in an infinite loop, as I want to change the text within the EventHandler

Comment: You can change the Text within the handler but you need to take down the event for the duration of the method. You can do that like this: 
call `this.TextChanged -= SomeClassName_TextChanged` to disable the event for this caller, do some stuff in the method and then call `this.TextChanged += SomeClassName_TextChanged` to re-activate the event.